# How to fix "TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" in tornado.wsgi?

Tags: tornado, wsgi, python-3.7

Im trying to use wsgi form tornado, coz the server accept only wsgi.

I've tried all variant of servers for tornado + wsgi, always getting this error: `__call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

```py
# app/__init__.py

import tornado.wsgi
import tornado.web
import wsgiref.simple_server


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("templates/index.html")

def routes():
    return [
    (r"/", MainHandler),
]

class Application(tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = routes()

        tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer.__init__(self, handlers)
```

```py
# wsgi.py 

import wsgiref.simple_server
from app import Application

application = Application()
server = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('', 8888, Application())
server.serve_forever()
```

Here is error trace:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2019 17:40:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

I expecte working tornado.wsgi, any help will be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WSGIContainer` goes the other direction: it lets you run wsgi apps on Tornado's HTTP server, not run tornado apps on a WSGI server.

In Tornado 5.1, you could do this with [WSGIAdapter](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch5.1/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIAdapter). In Tornado 6.0, `WSGIAdapter` is gone and there is no longer any way to run Tornado applications on a WSGI server; you must use Tornado's server.

Comment: ```py
from app import make_tornado_app
import tornado
import tornado.wsgi
import wsgiref.simple_server

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # application = make_tornado_app()
    # http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    # http_server.listen(8888)
    # tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    application = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(make_tornado_app())
    wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIAdapter(application)
    server = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('', 8888, wsgi_app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Still same error

Comment: Don't touch WSGIContainer - wrap your tornado app directly in `WSGIAdapter`.